# How to save a document that has a reference of an array in mongoose nodejs

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, nodejs-server

Help, I want to be able to post several items into the array,, I have two models control and subcontrol is referenced in the control model as an array.

My post api for the control:

```
router.post(
  '/add',
  auth,
  role.checkRole(role.ROLES.Admin, role.ROLES.Regulator),
  async (req, res) => {
    try {


    const subControl = new SubControl({...req.body}); 
    const subControlDoc = await subControl.save();
    const control = new Control({...req.body, subControl: subControlDoc._id}); 
    const savedControl = await control.save();

      res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: `Control has been added successfully!`,
        control: savedControl
      });
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error
        // error: 'Your request could not be processed. Please try again.'
      });
    }
  }
);
```

My postman:

```
{
   "mainControl": "1-3",
   "subControl": 
   [
   {
    "subControlNo": "1-3-1"
   },
    {
    "subControlNo": "1-3-2"
   }
   ],
  "description": "controldescription",
  "controlStatus": "Started",
  "mControlProgress": "Implemented",
  "sControlProgress": "Implemented",
  "comments": "ffffffffffffff",
  "actionOwner": "ROLE_ADMIN",
  "missingFiles": "file1 and file2",
  "recommendations": "revise control1 and 2"
  }
```

Response:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Control has been added successfully!",
    "control": {
        "_id": "621c9d2696f73d0ad39a0d12",
        "subControl": [
            "621c9d2696f73d0ad39a0d11"
        ],
        "controlStatus": "Started",
        "mControlProgress": "Implemented",
        "sControlProgress": "Implemented",
        "actionOwner": "ROLE_ADMIN",
        "mainControl": "1-3",
        "comments": "ffffffffffffff",
        "missingFiles": "file1 and file2",
        "recommendations": "revise control1 and 2",
        "created": "2022-02-28T10:00:06.982Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

I want to add several subcontrols into the control model. Plus if anyone recommends a book or the best way to learn nodejs and mongodb because I'm having some difficulties in finding resources.

Comment: I've been searching for a week, tried to loop, used .map nothing seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

This should ideally be a comment but sadly do not have enough reputation to comment on your post,

Can you edit the Code in your Post to cover the fact that you tried looping? Your latest code posted along with the question would be helpful.

Comment: I posted my second try through this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71368668/insert-an-array-of-object-ids-mongoose-nodejs/71369141#71369141 So I'm not sure if it's the right approach I've been reading about InsertMany I'll try it our also